# How to setup mass dynamic virtual hosts in nginx on docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

How can I setup mass dynamic virtual hosts in nginx [As seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199231/how-to-setup-mass-dynamic-virtual-hosts-in-nginx)
except using docker as the host machine?

I currently have it setup like this:

```
# default.conf
server {
   root /var/www/html/$http_host;
   server_name $http_host;
 }
```

And in my Dockerfile

```
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
```

And after I build the image and run it:

```
docker run -d 80:80 -v www/:/var/www/html
```

But when I point a new domain (example.dev) in my hosts file and make a www/example.dev/index.html. It doesn't work at all.

Comment: What is the issue that you get? Also is nginx loading with the config? are you able to browse the default site?

Comment: @TarunLalwani yeah its being loaded but I don't thing the domain is being redirected to the docker

Comment: Check the latest answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

The setup is correct and it works as i tested on my system. The only issue is that you are copying the file on a wrong path. The docker image doesn't use the `sites-enabled` path by default. The default config loads everything present in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`. So you need to copy to that path and rest all works great

```
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Make sure to map you volumes correctly. While testing I tested it using below docker command

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v $PWD/www/:/var/www/html -v $PWD/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf nginx
```

Below is the output on command line

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/test/www$ mkdir dev.tarunlalwani.com
vagrant@vagrant:~/test/www$ cd dev.tarunlalwani.com/
vagrant@vagrant:~/test/www/dev.tarunlalwani.com$ vim index.html
vagrant@vagrant:~/test/www/dev.tarunlalwani.com$ cat index.html
<h1>This is a test</h1>
```

Output on browser

[image: Nginx test output]

Comment: This doesn't change the web root. Everything is still being directed to the html/index.php and not html/example.com/index.php

Comment: Check the updated answer and see what you are doing wrong